# jQuery plugin (this) confusion when calling method from another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m building the following jQuery plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.showSelectList = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            /// Create the select element
            var select = document.createElement('select');
            select.className = "form-control input-sm";

            $(this).append(select);

            if (options)
                $(select).loadSelectListOptions(options);
        });
    }

    $.fn.loadSelectListOptions = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var htmlOptions = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                htmlOptions += '<option value="' + options[i].value + '">' + options[i].name + '</option>';
            }

            $(this).html = htmlOptions;
        });
    }

    $.fn.helloWorld = function () {
        var opt = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var option = { 'value': i, 'name': 'testname' + i };
            opt.push(option);
        }

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).showSelectList(opt);
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

I can load the `selectList` properly, but no matter what I do I can't load the `selectList` options using the `loadSelectListOptions` call. The call is handled, but the $(this) inside it does not point to the created `selectList`, but to something else. The result is that I get always an empty `selectList`.

Comment: `return $(this).each` just saved my life.  Thanks!  I was going insane trying to figure out how to target only one of each of the instances of my plugin!  ^_^  cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a function so you need to pass the option list as an argument

```
$(this).html(htmlOptions);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R8pwg/)

---

Since you have the same option list for all elements in the set, you can use

```
$.fn.loadSelectListOptions = function (options) {
    var htmlOptions = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        htmlOptions += '<option value="' + options[i].value + '">' + options[i].name + '</option>';
    }
    return this.html(htmlOptions);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R8pwg/3/)

Answer (score 3):

> $(this) inside it does not point to the created selectList, but to something else.

Yes - `$(this)` creates a jQuery wrapper around your selectList, and assigning to a `.html` property on that has no effect. What you want is either

```
this.innerHtml = htmlOptions;
```

or

```
$(this).html(htmlOptions);
```

Better however would be

```
$.fn.loadSelectListOptions = function (options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
            this.add(new Option(options[i].value, options[i].name));
    });
}
```

or

```
$.fn.loadSelectListOptions = function (options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
            $this.append(new Option(options[i].value, options[i].name));
    });
}
```